# Zerobrane: deinstall / autocomplete

Tags: zerobrane

I installed ZeroBraneStudio on mac os x (10.12) and run some tests. I set a breakpoint to a demo file included with ZeroBraneStudio. After deleting ZeroBraneStudio (moving the app to the trash) and making a fresh reinstall the breakpoint was at the same place. So this information was obviously stored somewhere outside of the Application/ZeroBraneStudio.app directory. Where?

After a fresh install I wrote in a new file some lua code and got no autocompletion. What I have to do to get this?

Comment: These are two distinct questions. It's better to limit your question to one question/problem. If you have multiple questions, post them as separate new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to remove [session configuration](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#session-configuration) file to restore the default configuration.

Comment: Thank you. And the auto-completion is now working also.